# LINQ Expression to extract specific quantity and value of numbers

Tags: c#, linq

I know I can do this using some for loops but was hoping that is could perhaps be done using some LINQ expression, I'm only vaguely familiar with LINQ, anyway here is my scenario, I have a list of integers containing unknown values like below , the size of the list will be known

```
var numList = new List<int>() { 12, 33, 24, 63, 45, 32, 3, 18, 22, 7, 10 };
```

What I need is to extract a new list of 4 integers which will contain numbers from the above list but only numbers whose addition with each other is greater than 100, so an example would be...

```
var extractedList1 = new List<int>() { 12, 33, 24, 45 };
var extractedList2 = new List<int>() { 33, 24, 63, 32 };
```

Obviously there more combinations here but I'm hoping there's an efficient way of achieving this, any help would be great.

---

UPDATE
Thanks Guys, both Selman22 and Rob P. solutions worked great and do exactly what I need when working with Lists of Integers, however to put another spin on things, I'm trying without much luck to adapt the code to work with a List of a Custom object called Combo

```
public class Combo
{
    public Combo(int weight, int value)
    {
        Weight = weight;
        Value = value;
    }

    public int Weight { get; set; }
    public int Value { get; set; }
}
```

In this scenario I would have a list of Combo Objects like below

```
        var c1 = new Combo(3, 7);
        var c2 = new Combo(4, 6);
        var c3 = new Combo(2, 10);
        var c4 = new Combo(3, 13);
        var c5 = new Combo(3, 5);
        var c6 = new Combo(2, 7);

        var comboList = new List<Combo>() { c1, c2, c3, c4, c5, c6 };
```

The value of each combo object would be its weight * value, so c1 would be 21, c2 would be 24 and so on. In this case I need to extract a list of 4 Combo objects where the addition of each is greater than 100, an example would be below

var extractedList1 = new List() { c1, c2, c3, c4 };

To adapt the existing code is probably a simple change but I'm not very familiar with LINQ at this time so again any help would be great and thanks for the help so far.

Comment: What if there is no combination of 4 number with sum of greater than 100?

Comment: LINQ is most likely going to be worse in terms of efficiency than a simple `for` loop.

Comment: There will be, the numList will actually contain about 100 numbers each one between 20 to 80 in value

Comment: If you're new to LINQ I think that firstly you should try without using it and then when you get the extepected results, find a way to "convert" it.

Comment: Is `33,33,33,33` also allowed?

Comment: I don't think you should be using Linq for that. Sure, it's fun and all to use Linq, but it's also fun to use a hammer, yet you don't use that tool to cut a wooden plank.

Comment: Do you need every possible solution? Because I can hardly see how it would be possible without generating a power set (And with 100 numbers, you can be sure it'll be inefficient). If you only need 1 solution, just pick the first 4 that are >= 25, which you can do with something like `.Where(x => x >= 25).Take(4)`

Answer (score 3):

Probably this is not an effient way but it should work:

```
var numList = new List<int>() { 12, 33, 24, 63, 45, 32, 3, 18, 22, 7, 10 };

/* get all combinations including duplicates like: 
12,12,12,12 - 12,12,12,34 - 12,12,12,24  and so on
then put them into an array int[] */

var combinations = from x in numList
            from y in numList
            from z in numList
            from t in numList
            select new [] {x, y, z, t};

/* eliminate the duplicates (like 12-12-12-12) and 
   filter them based on Sum */
var result =  combinations
             .Where(x => x.Sum() > 100 && x.Distinct().Count() == x.Length);

// get distinct combinations using a custom equality comparer 
var distinctResults = result.Distinct(new Comparer()).ToList();

public class Comparer : IEqualityComparer<int[]>
{
    public bool Equals(int[] x, int[] y)
    {
        return x.OrderBy(a => a).SequenceEqual(y.OrderBy(a => a));
    }

    public int GetHashCode(int[] obj)
    {
        return obj.Select(x => x.GetHashCode()).Sum();
    }
}
```

This use of `from` clause is called `Compound from clause` which allows you to get combinations easily, you can refer to [MSDN documentation](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb383978.aspx) to see more examples also [this article](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ericlippert/archive/2010/06/28/computing-a-cartesian-product-with-linq.aspx) from Eric Lippert might be helpful.

Comment: The only other thing I was hoping for was that I could package this within a method and the "4 integers" value would be a parameter, so I could get different sized lists 5,6,7 etc but I can probably just create separate methods for each using your code

Comment: Great Could you elaborate the process if possible

Answer (score 1):

Here is my take :

```
var numList = new List<int> { 12, 33, 24, 63, 45, 32, 3, 18, 22, 7, 10 };

var answers = (from a in numList
               from b in numList where a >= b 
               from c in numList where b >= c 
               from d in numList where c >= d
               select new { Sum = a + b + c + d, Ans = "{" + a  + " " + b + " " + c + " " + d + "}"} into temp
               where temp.Sum > 100
               select temp.Ans).Distinct() ;

foreach (var answer in answers)
    Console.WriteLine(answer);
```

Output is truncated (148 total):

```
{33 32 24 12}
{33 32 24 18}
{33 32 24 22}
{33 32 22 18}
{63 33 12 3}
{63 33 12 7}
{63 33 12 10}
{63 33 24 12}
{63 33 24 3}
{63 33 24 18}
{63 33 24 22}
{63 33 24 7}
{63 33 24 10}
{63 33 32 12}
{63 33 32 24}
{63 33 32 3}
{63 33 32 18}
{63 33 32 22}
{63 33 32 7}
{63 33 32 10}
{63 33 18 12}
{63 33 18 3}
{63 33 18 7}
{63 33 18 10}
{63 33 22 12}
{63 33 22 3}
{63 33 22 18}
{63 33 22 7}
{63 33 22 10}
{63 33 7 3}
{63 33 10 3}
{63 33 10 7}
{63 24 12 3}
{63 24 12 7}
{63 24 12 10}
{63 24 18 12}
{63 24 18 3}
```